# How to Send data as JSON objects over to MQTT broker

Tags: json, mqtt, paho

I'm using eclipse paho client on ubuntu and trying to send latitude, longitude and timestamp information as JSON format to the MQTT broker. How do I do that?

I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061737/how-to-send-objects-instead-of-string-in-mqtt-messages), But its not complete.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You just need to create your JSON object as a string then call getBytes() on that string to get the byte array to use as your payload in the message.

```
 MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage();
 message.setPayload("{foo: bar, lat: 0.23443, long: 12.3453245}".getBytes());
 client.publish("foo", message);
```

Comment: You better use String.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8) because if you not specify the charset it will use your platform defaults which may not UTF-8 (JSON is normally UTF-8)

Answer (score 7):

I don't know about that, but I use his:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt


send_msg = {
        'data_to_send': variable1,
        'also_send_this': variable2
}

client.publish("topic", payload=json.dumps(send_msg), qos=2, retain=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JavaScript, than you can use:

```
client.publish("foo", JSON.stringify({"foo": bar, "baz": 123})) // on sender side, and
```

`JSON.parse` on the receiver end.